# where can I find the sourcecode of predefined methods/classes in java?

Tags: java

> Java has number of predefined methods, but where to find the **source code of these methods**  ?

Answer (score 2):

In the JDK folder, there will be src.zip

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.X_XXX\src.zip**

If you want to see the source code of the Java Classes,

Open the Java Class -> Attach Source [If the source was not already attached] -> Point to the src.zip

Now the Source code for Java classes will be displayed in the editor